# Irreducible vs all local systems on a curve

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Is it true that for a simply-connected group $G$ and a (smooth projective) algebraic curve $X$ of genus $\geq 2$, the complement to the open consisting of irreducible $G$-local systems on $X$ inside the stack of all $G$-local systems, has codimension $\geq 2$, except when $g=2$ and $G=\operatorname{SL}_2$?

Comment: I hope you don't mind me fixing the LaTeX, and welcome to MO!